# Does GitHub use asymmetrical SSH?

Tags: git, github

I was learning how to use GitHub. Also, I am trying to use SSH way to interact with GitHub and I wonder what kind of SSH encryption GitHub uses. If it is Asymmetrical Encryption then we why don't we exchange with public keys, that is, we submit public key that we generate to GitHub but we do not get GitHub's public key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get GitHub's public key by connecting over SSH, it's exchanged automatically and used for host verification purposes as pert of the SSH session negotiation.

For example:

```
ssh-keyscan github.com
```

This returns something like this:

```
# github.com:22 SSH-2.0-babeld-2e9d163d
github.com ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABIwAAAQEAq2A7...GXA8VJiS5ap43JXiUFFAaQ==
# github.com:22 SSH-2.0-babeld-2e9d163d
# github.com:22 SSH-2.0-babeld-2e9d163d
```

It's all laid out there in the `ssh-rsa` block where the RSA public key is displayed. That information is normally stored in `~/.ssh/known_hosts` or equivalent.

Remember that RSA encryption is actually brutally slow, it depends on math using huge numbers often 2048 bits long or more, and is only used to bootstrap an alternate symmetric encryption method that's much faster. It's used primarily for identity validation and session key exchange. These symmetric encryption protocols are optimized for speed but depend on having a secure method of exchanging keys, something an asymmetric protocol like RSA provides.

For a primer on how this all comes together there's always the [SSH RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4253) or [a book on applied cryptography](https://www.schneier.com/books/applied_cryptography/).

Answer (score 0):

Git and GitHub use the same kind of encryption that's used for SSH in general.  In general, you do need to verify the SSH host key for the remote server (in this case, GitHub) by verifying the fingerprint when prompted.

The specific algorithms used vary depend on what's negotiated, but there will be some sort of key exchange (usually either Diffie-Hellman or Elliptic Curve Diffie-Hellman), public key signature algorithms on each side (RSA, DSA, ECDSA, or Ed25519), and either an ordinary symmetrical cipher and MAC (usually AES-CTR and HMAC with SHA-2) or an AEAD (AES-GCM or ChaCha20-Poly1305).